# PowerDesigner does not allow me to select the primary key in ER diagram

Tags: powerdesigner

Im projecting ER diagram in PowerDesigner16. In every entity PowerDesigner does not allow me to mark primary key. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can recreate a CDM and set Unique code and reuse Allow fields.The table structure is then copied.

Answer (score 0):

In the Conceptual Data Model, select Tools/Model Options...
Under Data Item, uncheck both the Unique code and Allow reuse fields.

Comment: I don't understand something... As you found, I think the problem was with the Unique Code, which prevents reused attributes from being Primary. But if these were reused attributes, how have you been able to uncheck Allow Reuse without getting the `The "allow reuse" preference cannot be deselected because at least one data item is shared by two entities.` message?